# Delphi DbGrid order by ID

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010, delphi-2009, dbgrid

Am showing data from database in `DBGrid` and in my `Command text`. I want to display data in ascending but all time is descending i dont know whay.

In command text in `Client DataSet` i set: `SELECT * FROM groups ORDER BY ID ASC` but when i compaile and grid is showed list is again start from `ID=3`.

[image]

What i do wrong

Comment: Use ClientDataSet.IndexDefs to define index by field ID. Then use ClientDataSet.IndexName. Or set "ID" in ClientDataSet.IndexFieldName.

Comment: See this : http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29056

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you set a value in the IndexFieldName property of your Dataset ?.

This would override any order in your commandtext, because no matter in which order you retrieve the data, your data will posteriorly be locally ordered as your IndexName or IndexFieldName defines.